# Extracting list of Strings from a file

Tags: python, regex

I have to extract 3 strings from a file as shown below:

I only need to extract the 3 strings before the keyword: ">> For"

I wrote the following code to extract the list of strings, however it does not extract correctly:

```
import re
import sys

contents = "JLYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKH                                        KMZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLI                                         KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJG                    J                    LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKH                    K                    MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLI                    L                    KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ                                        LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK                                        MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL                                        KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ                                        LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK                                        MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL                    >> For"

m = re.match(r'(.*)[A-Z]{20}\s{40}(.*)\s{20}>> For', contents)

if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Expected result for the above file:

```
['KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ', 'LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK', 'MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL']
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't extract correctly? What is the problem Is it giving you an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Yes, it gives me a wrong result.

Comment: If I create only one group (specific to what I want), then it doesn't return a match object either.

Comment: Sure, I will update the question with the expected result and what I am getting.

Comment: For "I only need to extract the 3 strings" which 3 strings? Just before `>> For` or any? What are the constraints for those 3 strings? Your regex only makes 2 groups so you can't extract 3 strings with it.

Comment: I updated the question now. The 3 strings just before ">> For" keyword.

Comment: It's not multi line. It contains spaces. I searched for 0xA in the entire file. There is no newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.findall('(\w{20}\s+\w{20}\s+\w{20}\s+)>> For', x)[0].split()
```

This should return what you're after:

```
['KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ', 'LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK', 'MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
([A-Z]{20})\s+([A-Z]{20})\s+([A-Z]{20})\s+>>\s*For
```

and capture group1, group2 and group3

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fyf5Mu/1)**

Sample python codes,

```
import re
contents = 'JLYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKH                                        KMZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLI                                         KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJG                    J                    LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKH                    K                    MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLI                    L                    KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ                                        LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK                                        MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL                                        KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ                                        LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK                                        MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL                    >> For'
m = re.match(r'.*([A-Z]{20})\s+([A-Z]{20})\s+([A-Z]{20})\s+>>\s*For', contents)
if m:
 print(m.group(1))
 print(m.group(2))
 print(m.group(3))
```

Which prints,

```
KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ
LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK
MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL
```

Answer (score 1):

simple and stupid non-regex solution, using `split` without delimiter so it doesn't care about newlines, spaces, etc...

```
contents = "JLYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKH                                        KMZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLI                                         KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJG                    J                    LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKH                    K                    MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLI                    L                    KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ                                        LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK                                        MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL                                        KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ                                        LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK                                        MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL                    >> For"

toks = contents.split()
for i in range(len(toks)-1):
    if toks[i]==">>" and toks[i+1]=="For":
        print(toks[i-3:i])
        break
```

prints:

```
['KXKEOLJJKYCRQKASDJGJ', 'LYLFPMKKLZDSRLBTEKHK', 'MZMGQNLLMAETSMCUFLIL']
```